# About counting in \newtheorems

Tags: count

For all my \newtheorems i want the below counting:

when i have for example only a section, i want the counting starts and following the number of section. Next, if i have subsection i want the counting starts and following the number of subsection and so on. how can i do this?

I don't want all the newtheorems follow the "subsection" counting. I want this counting when i have subsection

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

> **1 Section title A**
>
> Some text following.
>
> **1.1 Theorem.** *The statement of the theorem*
>
> Some text following.
>
> **1.2 Theorem.** *The statement of the theorem*
>
> Some text following.
>
> **1.1 Subsection title A**
>
> Some text following.
>
> **1.1.1 Theorem.** *The statement of the theorem*
>
> Some text following.
>
> **1.1.2 Theorem.** *The statement of the theorem*
>
> Some text following.
>
> **1.2 Subsection title B**
>
> **1.2.1 Theorem.** *The statement of the theorem*
>
> **2 Section title B**
>
> Some text following.
>
> **2.1 Theorem.** *The statement of the theorem*
>
> Some text following.
>
> **2.2 Theorem.** *The statement of the theorem*

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]% theorem is reset at subsections
\counterwithin*{theorem}{section}% theorem is also reset at sections
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    % we're after \subsection
    \thesubsection
  \else
    % no \subsection came along yet
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{theorem}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title A}

Some text following.

\begin{theorem}
The statement of the theorem
\end{theorem}

Some text following.

\begin{theorem}
The statement of the theorem
\end{theorem}

Some text following.

\subsection{Subsection title A}

Some text following.

\begin{theorem}
The statement of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
The statement of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Subsection title B}

Some text following.

\begin{theorem}
The statement of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{Section title B}

Some text following.

\begin{theorem}
The statement of the theorem
\end{theorem}

Some text following.

\begin{theorem}
The statement of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't. Just use

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

and your readers will be happier.